# Netlify & Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, netlify-function, netlify-cli

I am using Netlify Serverless Functions. I want to retrieve and save data to the firebase firestore. I use firebase-admin SDK.

The following is the initialization:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../keys/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```

I have multiple functions and I was wondering if there's a way to initialize the firebase once. Because I have to paste the same code above in all my functions which seems very inefficient and not best practice.

I have read on global initialization in NodeJs which just exports it and then imports that code where needed. But in netlify, it's a bit different since any file I place in functions folder will be used as URL endpoint.

I am very new to Netlify so clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a separate module file for initializing the firebase app and then can use its reference across all files.

Create a file named `firebase.js`

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../keys/serviceAccountKey.json");

var FirebaseApp = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

module.exports.FirebaseApp = FirebaseApp;
```

In another file, use it like below

```
var FirebaseApp = require('/firebase.js')
var collectionRef = FirebaseApp.database().ref("collection/");
```

Comment: Although I was able to type "ww.URL/.netlify/functions/firebase" and it reinitialized firebase which would throw error if I was to refresh page, saying its already been initialized. But I solved that by conditional checking ```if (firebase.apps.length === 0)```. My problem has been solved. But just for general knowledge, how do I tell Netlify to not include firebase.js as a URL